# What is the difference between spawn and fork?

Tags: windows, unix, fork, spawn

I have come across both `spawn` and `fork` in the context of starting a new process, but what is the difference?

Is there a difference in how this is handled/explained from unix to Windows?

Comment: `spawn` generally means the equivalent of `fork` + `exec`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`fork`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) is a standard system call in Unix, and does not exist in Windows. [`clone`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clone.2.html) is closely related (and on Linux they are implemented with the same internal functions). It is used to simply *duplicate* the currently-executing process.

On Windows, [`CreateProcess`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425.aspx) is used to create a new process by starting an on-disk executable.

Windows has a family of [`spawn`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20y988d2.aspx) functions, whereas [POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) specifies [`posix_spawn`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/posix_spawn.3.html). These accomplish what one typically wants to do: *execute some program*.